# Why is my Java Desktop Application Failing to Run?

Tags: java, swing, compiler-errors, javafx, netbeans-7

I have a Java Desktop Application with JavaFX 2 which I built and then I tried to run the JAR. The run failed so I ran it through the Command Line to get the errors. Here is what I got:

Edit: I updated the stack trace as some lines of code have been added/removed (The error is the same)

```
C:\Users\user\Desktop>java -jar DesktopApp.jar
Error: failed to msvcr100.dll java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't load library: C:\Users\user\Desktop\bin\msvcr100.dll
*** Fallback to Prism SW pipeline
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't load library: C:\Users\user\Desktop\bin\mat.dll
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.startup(QuantumToolkit.java:252)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:30)
        at javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel.initFx(JFXPanel.java:128)
        at javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel.<init>(JFXPanel.java:138)
        at app.Main.<clinit>(Main.java:150)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't load library: C:\Users\user\Desktop\bin\mat.dll
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.System.load(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.glass.utils.NativeLibLoader.loadLibraryFullPath(NativeLibLoader.java:155)
        at com.sun.glass.utils.NativeLibLoader.loadLibraryInternal(NativeLibLoader.java:85)
        at com.sun.glass.utils.NativeLibLoader.loadLibrary(NativeLibLoader.java:30)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.Application$1.run(Application.java:27)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.Application.loadNativeLibrary(Application.java:25)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.<clinit>(WinApplication.java:33)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinPlatformFactory.createApplication(WinPlatformFactory.java:20)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinPlatformFactory.createApplication(WinPlatformFactory.java:17)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.Application.Run(Application.java:49)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.startup(QuantumToolkit.java:242)
        ... 4 more
Could not find the main class: app.Main. Program will exit.
```

Edit: Line 150 in Main.java is `public static JFXPanel javafxPanel = new JFXPanel`. It appears that FX is requiring *mat.dll* and it is looking in the wrong place for it so it can't find it. I am running the program on a Vista (32bit) but when I run on Windows 7 (64bit) the first line (below) is not there.

```
Error: failed to msvcr100.dll java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't load library: C:\Users\user\Desktop\bin\msvcr100.dll
```

---

**After More Research:**

After some internet research I found the below similar discussions which I am still studying:

- http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2230876&tstart=31
- http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2250369
- http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=198599

It looks like *msvcr100.dll* and *mat.dll* are related to the JavaFX Runtime. I have the JavaFX Netbeans Plugin but I did not have the runtime. I now have it but that did not fix or change the problem. I found msvcr100.dll and mat.dll in ....netbeans\7.0\lib\javafx2-win\bin\ and also (after I installed the runtime) in C:\Program Files\Oracle\JavaFX Runtime 2.0\bin. It appears that my program is looking in the right place when run with Netbeans.

---

This is not the first time I ran this program. In past tries it was successful. Running through Netbeans does not produce any errors and the program runs properly.

Could this be an FX bug? How do I get my program to look in the right place and why is it not?

Comment: Do you have a constructor defined for your class? Also, is the default JVM the official one from SUN?

Comment: @Saher, Adding constructor `public Main() {}` did not help. The JVM is official either from java.com or sun.com. The error comes from the very same JVM that is used to successfully run from within NetBeans.

Comment: @Ajay, This is a Java Application with JavaFX 2 in it. I have a JFXPanel with a scene embedded into my Swing GUI.

Comment: You might want to take a look at this : http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2246431 . Very Similar discussion.

Comment: Does msvcr100.dll exist at C:\Users\user\Desktop\bin\msvcr100.dll?

Comment: @user489041 The folder C:\Users\user\Desktop\bin does not exist.

Comment: @Ajay, Thanks but I don't think the answer at the bottom is for the question at the top. And I already have build 34.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After even more research I decided to copy the bin folder located in *....netbeans\7.0\lib\javafx2-win* and also (after I installed the runtime) in *C:\Program Files\Oracle\JavaFX Runtime 2.0* to where my JAR is located.

This Worked! I guess the DLLs in the bin folder are required for JavaFX. Not sure why they would not automatically be included.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem but this is how I solved it. 
Under Windows, I created a batch file with the following lines

```
call c:\bkn-batfiles\setclasspath.bat 
set
java -jar  E:\DATA\JAVACLASSES-NETBEANS\search_files_with_java_fx\dist\search_files.jar 
pause
```

It runs great. In setcalsspath.bat I set the PATH as follows

```
SET PATH=.;C:\bkn-batfiles;
SET PATH=%PATH%c:\Program Files\java\jdk1.7.0_03\bin;
SET PATH=%PATH%c:\Program Files\java\jdk1.7.0_03\lib;
SET PATH=%PATH%C:\Program Files\Oracle\JavaFX 2.0 SDK\rt\bin;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your `PATH` is not set to point to required JNI libraries.

Follow these instructions:

1. Please type `echo %PATH%` and report back on what you see.
2. At the same command prompt, type `set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Users\user\Desktop\bin`
3. At the same command prompt, repeat your original command: `java -jar DesktopApp.jar`

Comment: C:\Users\user\Desktop\bin does not exist and I don't think its supposed to.

Comment: You do need to add the directory containing the missing DLLs to the path, but C:\Users\user\Desktop\bin directory is not the directory you're looking for.

Answer (score -2):

If i'm not mistaken, that is related the Microsoft Visual C Runtime. Try installing the Microsoft 
[Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package (x86)](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=5555)

However, a more interesting question to ask is why is you application trying to use this and why is it looking on your desktop for it?

EDIT: Try adding `addDllLocationToPath("C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\msvcr100.dll");` as the first line of code to your application.

```
    /**
     * Allows you to add a path to the library path during runtime
     * @param dllLocation The path you would like to add
     * @return True if the operation completed successfully, false otherwise
     */
    public static boolean addDllLocationToPath(final String dllLocation)
    {
        //our return value
        boolean retVal = false;
        try
        {
            System.setProperty("java.library.path", System.getProperty("java.library.path") + ";" + dllLocation);
            //get the sys path field
            Field fieldSysPath = ClassLoader.class.getDeclaredField("sys_paths");
            fieldSysPath.setAccessible(true);
            fieldSysPath.set(null, null);
            retVal = true;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.err.println("Could not modify path");
        }
        return retVal;
    }
```

Comment: I have moved my JAR, lib folder and readme to my desktop. But I'm not sure why it is looking for a bin folder with DLLs in it. My program is not using any DLLs, unless they are supposed to be included in a library.

Comment: They are probably being loaded by something you didnt code directly. Did you try installing the Redistributable Package?

Comment: Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 x64 Redistributable - 10.0.30319 is already on my computer. Please keep in mind that my program runs successfully when run with Netbeans.

Comment: I implemented your code and I did not get anything different. It is looking in the same place. Then I looked for msvcr100.dll in C:\WINDOWS\system32 and I did not find it.

Comment: Alright, I still say try my original suggestion of installing Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package (x86)

Comment: Take a look at my most recent edit. I don't thing the DLLs are Visual related.